# gdb - set watchpoint on a string outside the current context

Tags: c, gdb, watch

I have a char array called "my_string" in my main function.

When I try to set a watchpoint before running the program it will not work:

```
(gdb) watch my_string
No symbol "my_string" in current context.
```

1. Is there a way to set a watchpoint independently of the current scope/context for example before the program is being run?
2. Can I execute additional commands if a watch is triggered?
   For example when I do `watch $_streq(my_string, "hello")` I might want to automatically issue a `x/s my_string` when the value of `my_string` matches `hello`.

When I set a breakpoint at the first line of the program and run it before setting the watchpoint

```
(gdb) break 1
(gdb) run
(gdb) watch my_string
(gdb) continue
```

it will work, but I wonder if there is a way of doing it without being in the correct context.

Comment: "Ordinarily a watchpoint respects the scope of variables in expr (see below).
The -location argument tells gdb to instead watch the memory referred to
by expr."  Do you know the address of your variable?

Comment: No, you can't watch a local variable before it exists.